# Unity how can i swerve box with use joint?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

[image: :Joint]

I want to get an image like in the picture with code. I stacked boxes because i must add joint with code. I want to make the boxes look like this as the character slides left and right smoothly. And how can i smooth swerving control in unity for touch or mouse button?

I tried this codes for movement:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {

            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                firstPos = touch.position;
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                Swerving(touch.position);
        }

private void Swerving(Vector2 touch)
    {
        endPos = touch;
        float diff = endPos.x - firstPos.x;
        transform.Translate(diff * Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed, 0, 0);
    }
```

But not smooth swerving.

I tried hinge joint for image. I tried random values to motor,spring etc.  But it didnt work i have never used joints.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share your research.

Answer (score 3):

In general when dealing with physics you shouldn't use `transform` this break collision detection and other physics related things like your joints etc.

Try and rather go through the `Rigidbody` using e.g. [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) (or accordingly [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) if your are in 2D) within [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate.html) like e.g.

```
// or Rigidbody2D depending on your needs
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private Vector2 startPos;
private float movement;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// get user input in Update in general
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                startPos = touch.position;
                movement = 0;
                break;
        
            case TouchPhase.Stationary:
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                movement = touch.position.x - startPos.x;
                break;

            default:
                movement = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Apply Physics in FixedUpdate!
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + Vector3.right * movement * Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed);
}
```

---

However, in general the touch is a 2D **pixel space** position which might be quite different on different devices.

I would rather translate it into a 3D world space position and use something like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
[SerializeField] private Camera _mainCamera;

private float _offset;
private Plane? _hitPlane;
private Vector3 _targetPosition;

private void Awake()
{
    if (!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if (!_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

// get user input in Update in general
private void Update()
{
    _targetPosition = _rigidbody.position;

    if (Input.touchCount <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    switch (touch.phase)
    {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
        {
            // Check if you are touching the character
            var ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit) && hit.rigidbody == _rigidbody)
            {
                // create a virtual plane parallel to the camera view
                // passing the hit point
                _hitPlane = new Plane(-ray.direction, hit.point);

                // also store the offset from pivot to the hit point
                // we only care about the X axis
                _offset = (_rigidbody.position - hit.point).x;
            }

            break;
        }

        case TouchPhase.Stationary:
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
        {
            if (_hitPlane.HasValue)
            {
                // now instead keep ray casting against that virtual plane
                var ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
                if (_hitPlane.Value.Raycast(ray, out var distance))
                {
                    var hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
                    _targetPosition.x = hitPoint.x + _offset;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
            
        default:
            _hitPlane = null;
            break;
    }
}

// Apply Physics in FixedUpdate!
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(_targetPosition);
}
```

this makes sure your character is definitely placed on the X axis where you are dragging it without any delays but still complying with physics